# Customizing a download notification

Tags: android, android-download-manager

Based on another SO answer, I am using the following lines of code to download media files:

```
        DownloadManager.Request r = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(uri));

        // This put the download in the same Download dir the browser uses 
        r.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PODCASTS, fileName);

        // When downloading music and videos they will be listed in the player 
        // (Seems to be available since Honeycomb only) 
        r.allowScanningByMediaScanner();

        // Notify user when download is completed 
        // (Seems to be available since Honeycomb only)
        r.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);

        // Start download 
        DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

        dm.enqueue(r);
```

Now, that is all good except that I have a few questions:

1. The person who answered said that the notifications can be customized. **How can that be done?**
2. If I want to add a "cancel" button to cancel the download and delete the file, how do I do it? What do I need to implement to get this behavior?  :)

Comment: Have you succeeded ?

Comment: Nope, i havent succeeded

Comment: @AZ_ FInally found it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// Changing the Notification Title, Description, and its Visibility
DownloadManager mgr = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
Uri uri = Uri.parse("///.mp3");
DownloadManager.Request req = DownloadManager.Request(uri);
req.setTitle("Download");
req.setDescription("Kick Ass Description");
req.setVisibility(Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_COMPLETION_ONLY);
```

Pretty self-explanatory.